# You can't assign Perl $_ to a hash in a foreach statement

Tags: perl, foreach

I have tried everything I can think of (plus a tonne of random experiments) to assign $_ within the foreach statement to a hash. I know that you can assign it after the foreach line, but I have a very particular code limitation which doesn't allow me to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @x = qw(a c e g);
my $var = {'a'=>"z", 'b'=>"y", 'c'=>"x", 'd'=>"w", 'e'=>"v", 'f'=>"u", 'g'=>"t", 'h'=>"s"};
my $y = "e";
foreach $var->{$y} (@x){
    print "$y = $var->{$y}\n";
    $y = $var->{$y};
}
```

What I think is happening is the perl compiler cannot handle '{' and '}' characters in the position where it is looking for $VAR to assign $_ to. When I run the code not only do I get an error about the foreach line, but I also get a syntax error about the print line where there is no syntax error.

```
syntax error at ./foreach2var.pl line 9, near "$var->"
syntax error at ./foreach2var.pl line 12, near "}"
Execution of ./foreach2var.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Is there any way to assign $_ within the foreach statement directly to a hash reference rather than assigning it with `$var->{$y} = $_;` on the following line?

I am looking for the following output

```
e = a
a = c
c = e
e = g
```

Also, I am aware that the following works, but again, I have a particular code limitation which means I have to be able to handle foreach statements

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @x = qw(a c e g);
my $var = {'a'=>"z", 'b'=>"y", 'c'=>"x", 'd'=>"w", 'e'=>"v", 'f'=>"u", 'g'=>"t", 'h'=>"s"};
my $y = "e";
while($var->{$y} = shift @x){
    print "$y = $var->{$y}\n";
    $y = $var->{$y};
}
```

Comment: “I have a very particular code limitation which doesn't allow me to do this”  – could you explain this limitation a bit more? Why can't you write ordinary Perl code? Maybe resolving that limitation would provide a better solution. At the very least, explaining your EXACT limitations might enable creative answers other than saying “Perl doesn't work that way”.

Comment: I'm parsing perl code and modifying variables with another set of variables before running it in eval. This localised variable isn't part of the external variable set so I am trying to assign it to the external set to be consistent. Instead, it looks like the only option I have is to make a list of variables that cannot be modify and to let them run natively.

Comment: Or convert all `foreach my $x (@$y)` style statements into `while(my $x = shift @$y)` style statements before applying my other code.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `-s` switch in the shebang....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Foreach Loops in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops)

> The `foreach` loop iterates over a normal list value and sets the scalar variable VAR to be each element of the list in turn.

Thus, it needs a *variable* and the dereferenced computed-on-the-fly value you'd like to assign to isn't even an lvalue, much less a variable.

How strict is this "*variable*" requirment?  The rest of that paragraph goes

> If the variable is preceded with the keyword `my`, then it is lexically scoped, and is therefore visible only within the loop. Otherwise, the variable is implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop. If the variable was previously declared with my, it uses that variable instead of the global one, but it's still localized to the loop. This implicit localization occurs only in a `foreach` loop.

So we do need a variable there. The requirement is purely syntactical though.<sup>†</sup>

I'm not sure what precisely you need to do and what your restrictions are but

```
for (@x) { 
    $var->{$y} = $_;
    ...
}
```

does indeed assign as desired, as observed in the question.

Having it assigned as a topicalizer, `for $v (@ary) { }`, does have the extra property of localizing `$v` within the loop, as quoted above from docs, but you don't seem to need that part.

---

<sup>†</sup> One *can* localize parts of a complex structure. A command-line program

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'
    my $hr = { k => 2 };  say $hr->{k}; 
    SAVE: { local $hr->{k} = 7; say $hr->{k} }; 
    say $hr->{k}'
```

prints lines `2`, `7`, `2`.

Comment: My mistake was not understanding that the difference between `$x=1` and `$y->{$z}=1` is that the second isn't assigning to a variable.

Comment: @Mark Yes, in `$y->{$z}=1` the value (`1`) is assigned nicely to the (dereferenced) hashref's key, but the `for` loop mechanism does need an actual variable there for all it does, while `$y->{$z}` at that spot only puts a value on the stack and there is nothing for the localization mechanism to work with.  And this is only for `foreach`, as docs say!  (So, can do it (assign) in a `while` just fine)

Comment: Re "*and there is nothing for the localization mechanism to work with.*", No. It's purely a syntactical requirement. `local $d->{$s} = ...;` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ikegami "_It's purely a syntactical requirement_"  -- ok, a good point, thank you.  It _could_ localize `$y->{$z}`, assign, restore in the end etc.  (Reminds me of what's allowed for a filehandle in `open` -- a straight variable, or one must have a block. Here a block isn't accepted, nor are `()`. Tried...)

Comment: @Mark Please also see ikegami's correction in a comment here. I added a clarification to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. As per the documentation, it must be a variable.

It really doesn't make sense for it to be anything else because the variable's value is restored at the end of the loop.

```perl
$_ = "abc";
say;

for (qw( def ghi )) {
   say;
}

say;
```

Output:

```
abc
def
ghi
abc
```

---

You can get the desired output from each of the following:

```perl
my $prev = "e";
while ( @x ) {
   my $this = shift( @x );
   say "$prev = $this";
   $prev = $this;
}
```

```perl
my $prev = "e";
for my $this ( @x ) {
   say "$prev = $this";
   $prev = $this;
}
```

```perl
my $this = "e";
while ( @x ) {
   ( my $prev, $this ) = ( $this, shift( @x ) );
   say "$prev = $this";
}
```

```perl
unshift @x, "e";
for my $i ( 1 .. $#x ) {
   say "$x[ $i - 1 ] = $x[ $i ]";
}
```

Comment: If it must be a variable, do you think the refaliasing feature could be of use here? Or would the alias be destroyed by localization?

Comment: @amon The docs explicitly allow a refaliasing construct. The example provided is `foreach \my %hash (@array_of_hash_references) { ... }`